# User favorite movies api with .NET Core using EF

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-core

I've been having this problem for two days and I can't understand the problem

The idea is that I have a user with a login, I want to add that the user can add the movie to a list of favorites.

Here are my models:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string? username { get; set; }
    public string? email { get; set; }
    public string? password { get; set; }
    public string? firstName { get; set; }
    public string? lastName { get; set; }
    public string? address { get; set;}
    public ICollection<Favourite> Favourite{ get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string? title { get; set; }
    public string? description { get; set; }
    public string? gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime releaseDate { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile? CoverImage { get; set; }
}

public class Favourite
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public  Movie? Movie { get; set; }
    public  User? User{ get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas?

Help with a task for a student

Answer (score 1):

you should use Fluent API in your  you will override the OnModelCreating method and try to study the fluent API to make a many to many relattion between models.
here a good reference for quick understanding and applying for the ideas:   https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: @Rezan - IF you made it one student to many movies, then only one student could have multiple favorite movies. If you made it many students to one movie, then many students can have favorites, but only the same movies. So you need many-to-many